# What's the issue with this question that's about how to make the best use of a writing tool?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, questions

[Are there some ways to use wiktionary to find related terms more easily?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/62806/are-there-some-ways-to-use-wiktionary-to-find-related-terms-more-easily)

I already wrote a decent answer for my own question, but some people decided to downvote it, as though they don't want other people to know about the amazing things wiktionary can do right now, or maybe there's a valid reason, but I don't see any. Not a lot of people know about this tool and what it can do.

Answer (score 4):

### It's arbitrarily restrictive

Your question doesn't appear to describe the problem, but instead prompts for the solution you want to give. See the [comment under your post](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/62806/are-there-some-ways-to-use-wiktionary-to-find-related-terms-more-easily#comment105575_62806):

> Does it need to involve wiktionary? It might help to state the actual problem you're trying to solve, rather than just the issue with how you tried to solve it. –
> towr

That's a pretty clear description of why it might be getting downvoted. So instead of asking about trying to use wikitionary you should ask about the thing you are trying to achieve and leave it open for wikitionary to be a possible answer.

Additionally, most people don't like bare links, particularly at the start of posts. You could dramatically increase the readability of both your question and the self-answer by using some link formatting to provide better context for your links. I.e. `[Descriptive Text](Link)` or `[Descriptive Text][#]` with your links in a numbered list at the bottom of the post source. You can use the Hyperlink button in the editor or just hit Ctrl+L to insert the links with appropriate formating.